# Filepond and jquery returns error is not loading

Tags: jquery, filepond

I tried adding this jquery filepond, unfortunately. It doesn't upload

HTML

```
<input type="file" class="my-pond" />
```

JQUERY

```
$.fn.filepond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginFileEncode);

// Turn input element into a pond
$(".my-pond").filepond();

// Set allowMultiple property to true
$(".my-pond").filepond("allowMultiple", true);

// Listen for addfile event
$(".my-pond").on("FilePond:addfile", function (e) {
  console.log(e);
  $(".my-pond")
  .filepond("addFile", "/api/books")
  .then(function (file) {
    console.log("file added", file);
  });
});
```

This is the result when I try to upload

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is causing every file to be added to be added again, and then again, and then again.

```js
$(".my-pond").on("FilePond:addfile", function (e) {
  console.log(e);
  $(".my-pond")
  .filepond("addFile", "/api/books")
  .then(function (file) {
    console.log("file added", file);
  });
});
```

If you want to upload files you can set the FilePond `server` property with a URL to your server where you can handle the file upload:

```js
$(".my-pond").filepond({
  allowMultiple: true,
  server: '/post/files/to/this/location'
});
```

For more information see: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server/